# Caching forms or speeding up form generation

Tags: c#, .net, forms, caching

I have a zoomable form-interface like MS Word. The form contains +70 controls (Richtextbox, checkbox, etc) that are positioned all over the form.

The problem is that generating the form takes 2.5 seconds. Adding the 70 controls with panel.Controls.Add( ctrl) alone takes 1 second. (16 ms per call).

Is there a way to cache the whole blank form ?
Perhaps someone smart knows another method to generate the form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these controls being added through the designer, or are you adding them manually in code? If it's the latter, I would recommend calling `SuspendLayout` on the `Form` before you load the controls, then `ResumeLayout(true)` after you're finished loading.

Additionally, if these controls are being added while the form is visible, then suspending and resuming drawing can be a great help. See the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children) for more info on how to do that.

**EDIT**

Why do you need 70 `RichTextBox` controls? Have you considered redesigning the form so that so many aren't required (reusing some for multiple purposes, for instance)? Have you investigated your custom control to see if any speed can be gained in your own constructor?

Comment: Hi Adam,

Everything is generated manually.
We are already using SuspendLayout and SuspendDrawing (WM_SETREDRAW).

Comment: If that's the case, then any optimization would be on the component level. It's unlikely you're going to be able to get any additional performance increases.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tracing we discovered that the constructor for a Custom Inherited RichTextbox takes 7-8 ms per call.
70 controls means 70 * 8 = 560 ms.

Cant we just copy or clone an already constructed CustomRichTextBox ? Would that make a difference ?

Comment: The only way to create a new object is by invoking a constructor (at some level, regardless of the design pattern being used, *something* is invoking a constructor), so "copying" the object isn't possible.