# How to hide this line

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, mdi

I want to remove the line i am showing you with red arrows, the above [Image from application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz5md.png) line is generated on treeView_NodeMouseDoubleClick on a node. I am searching for a property or something to hide it.

Comment: Don't use the MDI framework.  Otherwise, see [C#.NET MDI bugs when programmatically hiding and showing again a maximized child form and when maximized, child form's icon cannot be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429438/719186)

Comment: i see, anyway thanks for your answer mate