# c# winform self customized scrollbar makes desktop flicker

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I use a textbox attach on a panel and then scroll the panel with my scrollbar instead of using windows default scroll bar.

But the problem is i use LockWindowUpdate  when scrolling,  which will affect the desktop window  and make it flicker  in  windows xp.

The very interesting thing is once I open a file browser in winXp and scroll the scrollbar in the file browser. Then go back to my application and scroll my customized scrollbar again , the flicker disappear.

is there any know what really happen in this case. how does LockWindowUpdate work?

Thanks

```
protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
{


         if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.First)
            {
                LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
            }
            else if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack /* || se.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition*/)
            {
                LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
                this.Refresh();
                LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
            }
            else
            {
                LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
                this.Invalidate();
                LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            base.OnScroll(se);
}
```

is the code for panel scroll event 
I just use my customized scroll bar to scroll the panel to right position.

if i use

```
SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
```

the panel still jitter a lot .

And i found today , if i just focus a icon in desktop , the desktop will not flicker any more, but i add code in program by using

```
SetForegroundWindow(Win32API.GetDesktopWindow());
```

it doesn't work also , So i am really tired of this issue.

is there anyone know this case?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
// Left empty to avoid undesirable flickering.
}
```

Comment: That works. Setting the ClassStyle bit to AllPaintingInWmPaint works too.

Answer (score 0):

This thread might be helpful:
[How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children)

Try to use WM_SETREDRAW (disable) instead of LockWindowUpdate();

Comment: since i am using a transparent textbox , if i stop redraw the background itself will flicker