# Strange behaviour while suspending main form painting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint

I have mdi forms which takes long time to load and thus bring a lot of flickering to the screen.
In order to prevent flickering i used the sendmessage API as described here [How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children).
We suspend painting of the **main form** of the app.

Doing this works fine except than we encountered various strange behaviours:

- If the user have a windows explorer instance behind, and he moves the mouse during the freeze, some parts of the left window of windows explorer begins to show up on the screen.
- Sometimes if the user click the mouse during paint freeze, our app looses the focus.

Is it because we freeze the main form ?

How could we prevent any drawing while loading our mdi form without any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Suspend/Resume is great in many cases.

However for the loading of a form I prefer to let drawing continue as normal but hide the form using Transparency until it is completely loaded.

```
Form f = new Form { Opacity = 0.01 };
f.Show();
f.BeginInvoke( new Action(() => f.Opacity = 0.99 ));
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately I need to freeze the painting of the main form while adding mdi forms. Changing the opacity to the mdi form does not seem to resolve the issue.