# Performance: Speeding up application

Tags: sql, vb.net, performance, loops

Attached, I have written some code that goes into our SQL DB, performs some queires, and then applies the results for 104 labels, on the windows form.

I have timed this procedure and it takes about 4 seconds which is way to long because my goal is to have this process done instantly so whenever a new employee is selected, his/her stats are loading as fast as possible.

My question: What can I do differenlty to make this goal possible?

```vb
Dim RESULT1 As Decimal 'declare this as global  
Dim RESULT2 As Decimal 'declare this as global

Private Sub Week(ByVal week As Integer)
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT " & _  
        "(SELECT CAST(SUM(TARGET_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL)/ CAST(SUM(ROUTE_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE WEEK_TIME = " & week & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' AND YEAR_TIME = '" & cbYear.Text & "' AND ACTIVE = 1) AS RESULT1," & _
        " (SELECT (SELECT CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN AS RESULT2 WHERE WEEK_TIME = " & week & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' AND YEAR_TIME = '" & cbYear.Text & "' AND ACTIVE = 1 AND APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID = 1)/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN AS RESULT2 WHERE WEEK_TIME = " & week & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' AND YEAR_TIME = '" & cbYear.Text & "' AND ACTIVE = 1)) AS RESULT2" & _
        " FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN "

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        ' Call Read before accessing data. 
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                RESULT1 = reader("RESULT1")
                RESULT2 = reader("RESULT2")
            End While
        Else
            RESULT1 = 0
            RESULT2 = 0
        End If
        ' Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub


Private Sub LoadWeeklyStats()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 51
        Week(i + 1)
        Dim LabelWkEff As String = "LblWkEff" + (i + 1).ToString
        Dim myArray1 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelWkEff, False)
        Dim myControl1 As Label = myArray1(0)
        myControl1.Text = RESULT1    


        Dim LabelDeliveryStat As String = "lblDeliveryStat" + (i + 1).ToString
        Dim myArray2 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelDeliveryStat, False)
        Dim myControl2 As Label = myArray2(0)
        myControl2.Text = RESULT2
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: -1. You throw in a bunch of (horrible) code and expect anyone to magically (probably with a Crystal Ball) guess where the problem is. You need to identify the bottleneck and then post a decent question. Close-voting.

Comment: Way too much code. Please strip this down considerably so that it is easy to see the queries you execute.

Comment: You could start by using [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `SqlCommand`

Comment: @HighCore , Im a rookie, man. but okay, let me rephrase the question better.

Comment: @usr, Ok, I stripped it down. I still can't format the sql statements so they're easy to see.

Comment: Like Bjørn-Roger said, you should SqlParameters. You have a big security issue right now. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Also, why are you looping all rows if you are just getting the last result? You should run your query and make sure it only return one result.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code - try over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bridge - I suppose it would depend on your definition of "working".

Answer (score 3):

I see at least three big glaring problems, though it's impossible to say which is the main culprit because I'm not sitting at your desk.

### Your SQL is Horrendous

Just look at the number of table queries in this query!

```
SELECT
        (
            SELECT
                    CAST(SUM(TARGET_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL) / CAST(SUM(ROUTE_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL)
            FROM
                    dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WITH(NOLOCK)
            WHERE
                    WEEK_TIME = @week
                AND APE_AREA_OBJID = @areaOBJID
                AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = @EmployeeName
                AND YEAR_TIME = @Year
                AND ACTIVE = 1
        ) AS RESULT1
    ,   (
            SELECT
                    (
                        SELECT
                                CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL)
                        FROM
                                dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN AS RESULT2
                        WHERE
                                WEEK_TIME = @week
                            AND APE_AREA_OBJID = @AreaOBJID
                            AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = @EmployeeName
                            AND YEAR_TIME = @Year
                            AND ACTIVE = 1
                            AND APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID = 1
                    ) / (
                        SELECT
                                CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL)
                        FROM
                                dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN AS RESULT2
                        WHERE
                                WEEK_TIME = @week
                            AND APE_AREA_OBJID = @AreaOBJID
                            AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = @EmployeeName
                            AND YEAR_TIME = @Year
                            AND ACTIVE = 1
                    )
        ) AS RESULT2
FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN
```

I can't even begin to refactor this for you because of the enormity of the problem and I don't know your schema, but I'd have to guess that this is one of the primary culprits. If at all possible, **cache** some or all of this in a single table (if performance really is your primary goal).

### Unnecessary looping

How many rows are you returning? And why are there multiple rows if you only need one? This looping is completely unnecessary and *might* be killing some performance for you:

```
    If reader.HasRows Then
        While reader.Read()
            RESULT1 = reader("RESULT1")
            RESULT2 = reader("RESULT2")
        End While
    Else
        RESULT1 = 0
        RESULT2 = 0
    End If
```

### Inefficiency * 52 + Repaint

As ineffecient as the code above is, you've made it worse by calling it **52 times**! I'm amazed this is only taking 4 seconds.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 51
    Week(i + 1)
    Dim LabelWkEff As String = "LblWkEff" + (i + 1).ToString
    Dim myArray1 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelWkEff, False)
    Dim myControl1 As Label = myArray1(0)
    myControl1.Text = RESULT1    


    Dim LabelDeliveryStat As String = "lblDeliveryStat" + (i + 1).ToString
    Dim myArray2 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelDeliveryStat, False)
    Dim myControl2 As Label = myArray2(0)
    myControl2.Text = RESULT2
Next
```

In addition to the ineffecient function call, you are forcing your form to repaint itself 104 times (once for `myControl1.Text` and again for `myControl2.Text`). Some WinForm controls (panels, etc) have a property or method you can set or call to allow you to load controls with a single repaint at the end ([SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) for example). If that doesn't work for you, you may find this post helpful:

[How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm pretty much learning as go. I've only been programming for about 3 months and there is soo much to learn. This site has helped me sooo much and I pretty much live by it. However, once I make a mistake and someone points it out, Im sure to never make the same mistake again which in turn improves my skill.