# Why do my WinForm controls flicker before the paint event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form in which I load a user control that contains 3 other user controls in it.

Every time I move to another tab and return to that user control the 3 controls inside it flickers even befor any event fires.

I tried every thing including:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

and

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams baseParams = base.CreateParams;
        baseParams.ExStyle |= 0x0200000;
        return baseParams;
    }
}
```

and

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams baseParams = base.CreateParams;
        baseParams.ExStyle &= 0x0200000;
        return baseParams;
    }
}
```

But nothing helps. The flickering happens befor any code runs.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Does this only happen when you run the project in debug mode? I have had similar issues in the past, but they weren't an issue when ran in release mode and/or outside of Visual Studio. Another less likely issue could be your display adapter drivers, I have seen that being the problem before, but admittedly only once.

Comment: The given info is quite inadequate to diagnose a flicker issue.  Hacking WS_EX_COMPOSITED cannot work when you do that in a user control, it must be a style flag that's turned on in a toplevel window.  The form.

Comment: I am compailing in debug, but it happens even whn I am running only the exe file outside Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried placing the hack WS_EX_COMPOSITED every where in the code.
In the main form, in the control... every where. And still nothing...

Comment: @LiranFridman You say you compile in debug, but have you tried it in release then ran outside Visual Studio? Just to make sure you have tried as that has been a solution to several of my more annoying issues in the past.

Comment: I tried now running in release and even running out of Visual Studio, and still the same pronblem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be happening because the background is being painted every time.

If *all* your painting is done in `OnPaint()` (including clearing the background - which your nested user controls are probably doing themselves, so that should be ok), then you can completely disable the background painting as follows:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    // Do nothing to disable background painting.
}
```

You might find that you need to also do that in the implementation of one or more of your nested user controls.

Also, if you are customising an existing Windows control to prevent it from flickering, you sometimes have to do the following (but this is NOT something you should do for one of your user controls):

```
private const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 20;

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted=true)]

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
    {
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    else
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I had to do that when customising a `ListView` to prevent it from flickering.

Answer (score 1):

If you're drawing lots of elements in the tabs, you might try disabling and resuming the "redraw" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children).

Comment: Also `DoubleBufferd = true` might help.