# SimpleOpenGlControl tab switching strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, opentk, tao-framework

I have a strange "flickering" problem with Tao' `SimpleOpenGlControl` control. I have 3 tab pages of a `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl`. The first and the second pages are filled with a `SimpleOpenGlControl` while on the third page there is a `MonthCalendar` (or a `Button` or something else). Consider this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        simpleOpenGlControl1.InitializeContexts();
        Gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        simpleOpenGlControl2.InitializeContexts();
        Gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    private void simpleOpenGlControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        // This delay makes the problem evident.
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    private void simpleOpenGlControl2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

If I switch from the first page to the second, the third, the second and to the first again I see the calendar as a sort of background before the first control is painted.

I saw from the source code that the `OnPaintBackground` method is overridden and that the base class `UserControl.OnPaintBackground` method is not called. Could it be the problem?

Edit:

I tried to override the `OnPaintBackground` method in a subclass but it is not called. Actually the control' styles are initialized in this way:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, false);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
```

I suspect that the tab control buffering is conflicting with that of the `SimpleOpenGlControl` in some way.

The `AutoMakeCurrent` and `AutoSwapBuffers` properties are set to true. I tried to call `SwapBuffers()` before the `TabPage` change and the result is better but not perfect: going back and forward through the tabs cause the `MonthCalendar` to flash sometime.

Edit2:

I've the same problem using the `OpenTK.GLControl`. No problem using dotNet controls as `PictureBox`.

Edit3:

I tried also overriding `WndProc` has described in [Why do my WinForm controls flicker before the paint event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231272/why-do-my-winform-controls-flicker-before-the-paint-event) but the result is the same.
Also this [answer](http://www.opentk.com/node/3642#comment-15563) on the OpenTk forums doesn't help.

It seems impossible that there is no solution to this problem!

Comment: I suspect the fact that you're putting the control to sleep for 2 seconds does not help anything. In the worst-case, that is a full 2 seconds before it can respond to any event. You need some code to wake the sleeping threads up.

Comment: The real code doesn't have the sleep call. The problem is only less evident.