# Draw always updating ractangle on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to have a rectangle that changes size based on a value, But I cannot get it to update. If I draw the rectangle with set values it shows up, But if I then add a "*" operator to it, it does not show.

I've never used winform graphics before, this is based on other posts i've come across.

The code:

```
private void Send()
        {
            int l = 25, r = 20; // Testing values

            using (Graphics g = this.MainPanel.CreateGraphics())
            {

                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen);

                g.FillRectangle(brush, 59, 74, 16, 56 * (l / 100));
                g.FillRectangle(brush, 81, 74, 16, 56 * (r / 100));

                brush.Dispose();
                this.Invalidate();
            }

            string start = l + ":" + r + ".";
            char[] end = start.ToCharArray();
            port.Write(new string(end));
        }
```

This bit of code runs every 15ms if that matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RectangleF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. The height of your calculated rectangle is 0, because the int value is rounded to 0 when you're dividing. Better use [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) and [RectangleF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, in my opinion is better to calculate the rectangle you need to draw in the method `Send()`, and then invalidate the `Form`. You paint the rectangles in the method [OnPaint()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the form. For example:

```
    private void Send()
    {
        float l = 25, r = 20; // Testing values

        mRectangle1 = new RectangleF(59, 74, 16, 56 * (l / 100));
        mRectangle2 = new RectangleF(81, 74, 16, 56 * (r / 100));

        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, mRectangle1);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, mRectangle2);
        }
    }

    private RectangleF mRectangle1;
    private RectangleF mRectangle2;
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Seems to work great apart from its always on the bottom. How would I make it be on the top of everything.

Comment: If you want to paint over child controls, the solution is a little bit more complicated. Take a look to this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26071/Draw-Over-WinForms-Controls