# How can I cancel an ongoing `Refresh()` process?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My application has bound parameters that require the screen to be redrawn, some parameters cause the redraw to take a little longer.

I created an interface to handle this with my accessors so that for the parameters requiring this, I call `NotifyRedrawRequired()` which eventually leads to a call to `this.Refresh();`.

My code:

```
public delegate void MyFormDrawRequiredEventHandler(object sender, string callerName);

public MyForm() : Form {
    public MyForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.DrawRequired += MyForm_DrawRequired;
    }

    void MyForm_DrawRequired(object sender, string callerName) { this.Refresh(); }

    [Category("Action")]
    [Description("Fires when a redraw is required by the class.")]
    public event MyFormDrawRequiredEventHandler DrawRequired;

    protected virtual void NotifyDrawRequired([CallerMemberName] String callerName = "")
    {
        if (DrawRequired != null) { DrawRequired(this, callerName); }
    }

    private int blockSpacing;
    public int BlockSpacing
    {
        get { return blockSpacing; }
        set
        {
            if (blockSpacing != value)
            {
                blockSpacing = value;
                NotifyDrawRequired();
            }
        }
    }
    /// Rest of the form code ...
}
```

***What would the best way to avoid having `Refresh()` events pile up?*** Is canceling the `Refresh()` process a simple thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me way too long to find a reference to refresh my memory on the name, but while this isn't 100% Winforms, for some reason, this used to be a semi-standard practice programming against the raw Windows API.  You can [suspend painting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children) and restart it by sending the `WM_SETREDRAW` message.

When you do it depends largely on your application.  I used to use timers.  Too many in too short a time, turn them off.  None in a while or we're nearing a couple of "movie frames" without an update, turn'em back on.

If Windows can't update the window, it collects the `Invalidate`d rectangles for when it can update.