# How to stop flickering on windows form?

Tags: c#, devexpress, flicker

How to stop flickering on windows form?

I have used below code that will help to stop flickering

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
         CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
         cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         return cp;
    }
}
```

but using this my CPU usage goes to 100%.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say windows form.. do you mean winforms? when does the flickering occur? what controls are on your form? if any tab controls your already in a bad position. the only real solution is to convert to wpf.

Comment: Do u use the Onpaint event of the form,also check if any one your controls is responsible for this. u can set the DoubleBuffer of the form to true.

Answer (score 2):

Most often than not, just setting the Form's `DobuleBuffered` property to `True` will correct flickering and related drawing problems. Doesn't require any specialized code.

Have you given it a try?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you posted the code that causes your form to flicker.
without that this is the most general solution I can think of (except for turning off your monitor :0)):

Try using the answer suggested in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children/487757#487757).

Basically you need to:

Create the following class:

```
class DrawingControl
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11; 

    public static void SuspendDrawing( Control parent )
    {
        SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
    }

    public static void ResumeDrawing( Control parent )
    {
        SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
        parent.Refresh();
    }
 }
```

In your form add a call before the flickering to `SuspendDrawing` and after it to `ResumeDrawing`
Something like:

```
public void MyFlickeringFunction()
 {
     try
     {
         SuspendDrawing(this);
         /*Your code goes here...*/
     }
     finally
     {
          ResumeDrawing(this)
     }
 }
```