# Winform Customer ListBox How to Suspend OnPaint method

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a custom listbox that inherits the `WinForms ListBox` class, like so.

```
  public class UserListBox : ListBox
  {        
     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         // Omitted for brevity...
     }
  }
```

I add a filter on this `ListBox` (just like `GridView` control's DefaultView) but when I change the items, the OnPaint method is called regardless. I cannot call other method like remove.

I test SendMessage WM_SETREDRAW to suspend update, but that isn't working.

How can I suspend the call to the `OnPaint` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original**

I'm not sure why you would ever want to actually do this, but it is possible. With `WinForms` you can actually P/Invoke into some native calls and attempt to manage things like the [windows messaging loop](https://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip54.asp). In all honesty, I would suggest trying to avoid doing this. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

> How can I suspend the Control.OnPaint method?

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children) to check out an example.

**Update**

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation, you're doing it correctly. Could you please provide some more source code such that I could have another look?

Comment: Thanks, I test the link above.                       `public class Win32ApiUtils
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
        private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11; 
        public static void SuspendDrawing(Control parent)
        {
            SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
        }

        public static void ResumeDrawing(Control parent)
        {
            SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
            parent.Refresh();
        }
    }`

Comment: i call the SuspendDrawing method for my customer listbox.but that isn't working.