# vb.net fastest way to remove duplicates from listview?

Tags: vb.net, listview, duplicates

Does anyone have a quicker and better way to remove duplicates from a listview? I am currently doing it like this: I sort the items alphabetically, and then it checks the item below and compares it with the one above.

This is time consuming though.. When I enter 20.000 records into an excel sheet, and remove duplicates it takes a few miliseconds, but with this code below it takes hours to check 20.000 items in vb.net. Does anyone know of a faster method?

```
 Dim max As Integer = ListView2.Items.Count
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items

        If i = max Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If i > 0 Then

            If item.Text = ListView2.Items(i - 1).Text Then
                max -= 1
                item.Remove()
                i -= 1
            End If
        End If

        i += 1

        Label4.Text = "Total domains: " & ListView2.Items.Count

    Next
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to remove items during a for-each loop.  Usually it's better to work off a copy of the list or go in reverse order in a loop.  The "slowness" might be attributed to the control trying to redraw everything on every item removal.  See [How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/487661/719186)

Comment: Similarly, use a DataGridView bound to a datasource which would allow you to easily check that source and not add dupes to begin with.  In any case managing the source will be faster.  Controls are not intended for data storage but to present a *view* of the data to the user.

Comment: @Plutonix I might do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Linq based solution to get distinct items based on `item.Text` and sort the items.  If sorting is not required, you can remove the `OrderBy` part.

```
Private Shared Sub RemoveDuplicatesAndSort(lv As ListView)
    Dim distictItems As ListViewItem() = lv.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem)().Distinct(New LVItemComparer()).OrderBy(Function(item As ListViewItem) item.Text).ToArray
    lv.BeginUpdate() ' suppress screen updates
    lv.Items.Clear()
    lv.Items.AddRange(distictItems)
    lv.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Private Class LVItemComparer : Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ListViewItem)
    Public Function Equals1(x As ListViewItem, y As ListViewItem) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ListViewItem).Equals
        Return x.Text.Equals(y.Text)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As ListViewItem) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of ListViewItem).GetHashCode
        Return obj.Text.GetHashCode
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashSet` which will accept only unique values.

```
Dim itemsText = ListView2.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Select(Function(item) item.Text)
Dim uniquesValues As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)(itemsText)
```

Then set items from `HashSet` to the `ListView`.

Comment: I get 2 errors with this code. 1) 'Select' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection'. and 2) Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:

Comment: @Anders - you need to cast items to `ListViewItem` before using `Select` - check updated answer

Comment: So it will store the new items to uniquesValues? I have been testing it, but doesn't really seem to work.