# 'Pause' Display while control elements are updated (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

So, I am kind of asking a question for a hypothetical situation here.

I am producing a Windows Form App made to show multiple windows of data on the screen at the same time.  To accomplish this, I have decided to put a Table Layout Panel in the main form to act as a container for all of the data windows I will open.

The width and height of each cell of the Table Layout Panel will change depending on how many windows are open.  For example, if just one window is open, it takes up 100% of the width and height of the container area.  Alternatively if 3 windows are open, all the windows will have a size equal to 50% of the container's width and height.

Now let's assume each of these Windows have 20 different control elements, which are all used to help the user search through the data shown in each window.  Additionally, all of these elements dynamically resize and relocate themselves as the dimensions of the window they are in change.

With all of these moving elements, when a screen is added or removed it can be assumed that there will be a good deal of glitching going on on the screen that may alarm the user.  Thus we get to my question.

Is there a way to 'pause' the display of a Windows Form Application so that the user doesn't see everything on change modifying itself?  I can't seem to find anything like while looking online so that is why I am asking here.

Comment: I think you're looking to suspend drawing, check out this post and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487757/6664878)

Comment: @soohoonigan Thanks for the link.  That may be what I am looking for, I'll give it a bit more Googling.